# $_REQUEST response from paypal not working on mobile

Tags: php, paypal

I am having problem in getting response from paypal.

My return url is http://domain.com/success.php

When user click at Return to test store 
print_r($_REQUEST) in success.php

It is showing following response

1. In PC

   ```
   Array
   (
   [p] => success
   [mc_gross] => 1.00
   [protection_eligibility] => Eligible
   [address_status] => confirmed
   [payer_id] => 5NW3P8FUYFYFE
   [tax] => 0.00
   [address_street] => 1 Main Terrace
   [payment_date] => 04:27:19 Aug 05, 2016 PDT
   [payment_status] => Completed
   [charset] => windows-1252
   [address_zip] => W12 4LQ
   [first_name] => ccc
   [mc_fee] => 0.34
   [address_country_code] => GB
   [address_name] => xxxxx.com
   [notify_version] => 3.8
   [custom] => xxxxxx
   [payer_status] => verified
   [business] => xxx@gmail.com
   [address_country] => United Kingdom
   [address_city] => Wolverhampton
   [quantity] => 1
   [payer_email] => xxxxx@xx.com
   [verify_sign] => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A9G0cMQOKCptUlk3ZM6auE-mf507
   [txn_id] => 4X819350VF4549832
   [payment_type] => instant
   [payer_business_name] => ccccc.com
   [last_name] => xse
   [address_state] => West Midlands
   [receiver_email] => xxx@gmail.com
   [payment_fee] => 0.34
   [receiver_id] => WDYSUEU9Z5VC6
   [txn_type] => web_accept
   [item_name] => xxxxx
   [mc_currency] => USD
   [item_number] => xxx item
   [residence_country] => GB
   [test_ipn] => 1
   [handling_amount] => 0.00
   [transaction_subject] => 
   [payment_gross] => 1.00
   [shipping] => 0.00
   [auth] => AWUmb3MaMhQQFXjVxW1eCghg4fBj3JHJOnqhWlzwHCLbh4JSLPN8gunCHWzCzMbvWJT1GrRQVf4hdhFiNvCMmQ
   [_ga] => GA1.2.92304254.1470082055
   [PHPSESSID] => 6enc14j62cp14fkrdarog2gin3
   )
   ```
2. In Mobile the resposnse is

   ```
   Array
    (
   [_ga] => GA1.2.92304254.1470082055
   [PHPSESSID] => 6enc14j62cp14fkrdarog2gin3
   )
   ```

Please help me so that i can get full response on mobile device too.
Thanks

Comment: In the future use `example.com` instead of `domain.com`. It's how we do it on [so].

Comment: The response is depend on the paypal sdk. Mobile SDK and website API both response are different.

Comment: so what to do in that case?

Comment: besides I am not using paypal SDK. I am simply sending values to paypal using from